# Crystal reports Groups

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a grouped report that has three levels like this:

```
  Group #1 Name: Warehouse.Description
   Group #2 Name: reportCat.Description
   Group #3 Name: inventory.Description
```

Besides the inventory description I want to display the quantity and sales amount.

For example:

```
Description   qty     sales

Warehouse1
Liquor
Corona         4      24.00
Heineken       10     30.00

Warehouse2
Liquor
Corona         2      12.00
Heineken       5     15.00
```

But when I run the report the values that I get for each of the `Group #3` fields 
is a summarization of all the values for that specific product without being 
broken down by the `Group #`1 warehouse.

Meaning that I get the same values for Warehouse1 and Warehouse2.

Wondering if I am missing something in my approach.

Thanks

Comment: How are you taking summary and where are you viewing the sumary?

Comment: if you have grouped as explained in question then there is no possibility og getting wrong results.. have you checked the database for values present as per your requirement?